# how to check for NULL returned from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, null

I need to check if my stored procedure returned null value.
Currently I have the following code:

```
public static bool MyMethod(String isoNum)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    bool regionExists = true;
    try
    {
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["String"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPU_GetRegionBasedOnIso", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isoNum", isoNum);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                **<<Here I need to check for NULL value>>** 
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new System.Exception(e.Message.ToString());
    }
    return regionExists;
}
```

What is the best way to check for NULL here?

Thank you

Comment: Are you returning from your sproc with a RETURN statement or a SELECT statement?

Comment: Are you returning a single value (something like "SELECT @foo") or are you returning multiple columns/rows?

Comment: Single value will be returned: either null or a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader` and compare against `DBNull.Value`.

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == DBNull.Value)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar and DBNull have been around since .NET 1.0.

Comment: I'm talking about `var`